# Is there any way to improve tesseract OCR with small fonts?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use tesseract-OCR via python-tesseract to read a low resolution font that looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately that image returns

```
ZIJZHZI
```

I think the resolution is too low and that is causing problems. I've tried magnifying the image, and cropping it down to individual characters, but neither of these provide much improvement. Is there anything else I should consider doing, preferably something that could be done using the Python Imaging Library? Or should I just give up/train tesseract.

For what it's worth, the PIL has the following built in filters:

> BLUR, CONTOUR, DETAIL, EDGE_ENHANCE,
>   EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE, EMBOSS, FIND_EDGES,
>   SMOOTH, SMOOTH_MORE, and SHARPEN

Comment: try x6 resizing with anti-aliasing. I've tried that on screenshots and got good results.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've tried to magnify the image with:

```
  convert -resize 400% in.bmp out.bmp
```

And then read it:

```
  tesseract out.bmp res
```

The result is correct:

```
  100
```

Comment: convert is part of ImageMagick, and it just resizes the image

Comment: it helped me at normal resolution the result was "mm readmxs’", after resize the output file reads "Can you read this?"

Comment: @RobertMihaiIonas, can you provide the image?

Comment: `convert` do the job but `tesseract out.bmp stdout -psm 12` the `psm 12` was requisite