# Convert command not working in windows

Tags: image, resize, imagemagick, tesseract, imagemagick-convert

Installed ImageMagick-7.0.4-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe for resolving the issue of Tesseract facing problems with smaller font explained in this Stackoverflow question [Is there any way to improve tesseract OCR with small fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909396/is-there-any-way-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-with-small-fonts)

I ran the following convert command. But it still says invalid parameter.

```
C:\Users\rt\Desktop\Sample_Files>convert -resize 400% image5.jpg image5out.jpg
Invalid Parameter - 400%
```

and when I ran this

```
C:\Users\rt\Desktop\Sample_Files>where convert.exe
C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe
```

so just one convert.exe, I guess which belongs to windows convert.

I am missing something or something wrong with Tesseract or ImageMagick? can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`convert` is now replaced by `magick` to avoid clashing with Windows `CONVERT.EXE`.

`identify` becomes `magick identify`.

`mogrify` becomes `magick mogrify`. Likewise, `animate`, `compare`, `compose` and `stream`.

Or alternatively, to keep using the old command names, you must tick the `Legacy` box when installing **ImageMagick**.