# Powershell can not call ImageMagick commands - IM Montage

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I wrote a script in PowerShell and I am having various success calling Image Magick's montage.exe on different computers. The computer on which I wrote the script has no problem executing the 'montage' command, however on another computer with IM Installed the script errors out:

```
montage : The term 'montage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At \\Server\Contact_Sheet_Local.ps1:51 char:9
+         montage -verbose -label %t -pointsize 20 -background '#FFFFFF ...
+         ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (montage:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried using `montage.exe` and even tried the entire path `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\montage.exe`. Additionally I tried setting the directory first:

```
Set-Location -Path 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16'
montage...
```

Each time on a particular computer this fails. I have tried with IM versions 7.0.3-Q16 and 6.9.1-6-Q8 both x64 as both computers are x64

In the past, I have created scripts in .bat that use ImageMagick and I had to define the full path to the .exe as I mentioned above. But this doesn't seem to help in PowerShell.

Does anyone have any advice or experience with this problem?

Comment: `.\montage`  PowerShell doesn't search the current working directory unless you specify it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774063/2836621

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42099622/2836621

Answer (score 0):

If your path has spaces, it will fail if you're just trying to execute based on that.  You'll want to utilize the dot operator

```
$Exe = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-6-Q8\montage.exe'
If (-not (Test-Path -Path $Exe))
{
    $Exe = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\montage.exe'
}
. $Exe -arg1 -etc
```

Comment: Hello again and thanks for the advice @TheIncorrigible1. While I am sure this will work, I ended up finding that the error only occured in ISE, and that right clicking and running with PowerShell did not produce an error.

I will keep the dot operator in mind as I am not previously familiar.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `&` to invoke the executable, not `.` to dot-source it. (While this "works," it's not correct semantically speaking.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart What's your reasoning?

Comment: @Garrett That's due to where your script is executing.

Comment: Dot-sourcing affects scope and executes the following in the current scope instead of creating a new scope (which is the normal and default behavior of scripts). You should not dot-source unless you understand exactly what it does. (Read the `about_Scopes` documentation for details.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Executing in a new scope causes issues with concurrency if you want something to execute after the exe completes.  I do understand the difference, I wanted to see your reasoning.

Comment: If you do understand, then IMO it's not good to recommend it as a solution for this problem when we already have the `&` operator, which does not affect scope. Someone reading this answer might misunderstand the difference between the operators, use `.`, and create some odd problems for themselves.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 *Executing in a new scope causes issues with concurrency if you want something to execute after the exe completes.* Using `.` vs `&` have no effect on `.exe` commands, because external commands have no understanding of PowerShell scopes. And I am agree with @Bill_Stewart: you should prefer `&` over `.` unless you really want dot source semantic.

Comment: @PetSerAl I quite agree; one should prefer the semantically correct operator.

Comment: Thanks for all the great input everyone.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does not execute programs in the current directory by default. If you want to run an executable that's sitting in the current directory, prefix the executable's name with `.\` or `./`. Example:

```
Set-Location "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16"
.\montage.exe ...
```

If you have an executable's name in a string or string variable and you want to execute it, you can do so using the `&` (call or invocation) operator:

```
& "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\montage.exe" ...
```

If you specify a path and filename that doesn't contain spaces, the `&` operator isn't required; example:

```
C:\ImageMagick\montage.exe ...
```

You could also write it this way:

```
& C:\ImageMagick\montage.exe ...
```

If you have an executable's filename in a string variable and you want to execute it, use `&`; example:

```
$execName = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\montage.exe"
& $execName ...
```

Comment: This is all great info @Bill_Stewart . Thanks for the valuable input.

Comment: @Garrett if you find an answer helpful it is customary to upvote it.

Comment: Hi @Bill Stewart, I didn't end up using either provided solution as the issue was only occurring in ISE and running the PowerShell script provides the intended output. That said, I found the information you provided helpful and plan use this knowledge in the future.

Comment: There is no functional difference in behavior between the console version of PowerShell and the ISE.