# OCR small image with python

Tags: python-2.7, ocr, python-tesseract

i need to ocr small images with python 2.7, contains a price.

[image]

as you can see the image is very small , and contains some values.

my goal is to decode to : 654.10

i try with tesseract but i had no luck.

```
import pytesseract
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('example.png') , lang='eng', boxes=False,config='--psm 10 --eom 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=€0123456789'))
```

i get :

```
€553 1
```

i try with an online converter and work like a charm (https://convertio.co/it/ocr/) so i think it will be possibile.

someone have a better idea ?

Thanks

(sorry for my bad english)

UPDATE :

i try to threshold the image without any luck ... again ...

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('cropped.png')
grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, threshold2 = cv2.threshold(grayscaled,125,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite('threshold.jpeg',threshold2)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('threshold.jpeg') , lang='eng', boxes=False,config='--psm 10 --eom 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'))
```

output : 553 0
image output : [image]

ps. i cropped the original image deleting the € sign ... but still got the error.

Thanks

Comment: Pre-processing the image to make the text clearer may help. Something similar to 'threshold' in photoshop.

Comment: @Paandittya unfortunately it doesn't work ... anyway ... another idea ? Thanks

Comment: so i was thinking on the lines of resizing the image to 2x-3x and then try to get text out of it. In process I landed upon this thread [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4945131/7636315). If you have not tried this then give it a go. This seems like a similar problem as you are facing. Hope this would do the trick.

Comment: @Paandittya it works thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome mate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my issue by resize the image and then apply the threshold.

this code will increase the dimension of the image :

```
    basewidth = 300
    img = Image.open(saved_location)
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(saved_location)
```

Thanks to the user post in the comments.